# fancybox navigation arrows

Tags: jquery, animation, fancybox

I've tried for hours to resolve this issue. I would sincerely appreciate some help.

I'm trying to implement a jquery animation for the navigation arrows that appear once a [grouped] item is opened up in fancybox. The left or right navigation arrows appear after hovering over the #fancybox-left or #fancybox-right portion that divides the object. For instance, I've positioned the right arrow (defined as #fancybox-right-ico) by setting "right: -__px" under #fancybox-right:hover span so that the arrow is just outside of #fancyboxcontent.

I want to use the jquery animation function so that the #fancybox-right-ico appears to slide out from under #fancyboxcontent instead of just appearing as it does by default.

I've tried using [this tutorial](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2009/11/30/beautiful-slide-out-navigation-a-css-and-jquery-tutorial/) for reference.

Where should I place the following code in the fancybox files and how should I label '#navigation a', '#navigation > li', and 'a'?

```
$(function() {

 $('#navigation a').stop().animate({'marginLeft':'-85px'},1000);

 $('#navigation > li').hover(
  function () {
   $('a',$(this)).stop().animate({'marginLeft':'-2px'},200);
  },
  function () {
   $('a',$(this)).stop().animate({'marginLeft':'-85px'},200);
  }
 );
});
```

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UagVd/11/)):

```
$("a").fancybox({
  onComplete: function() {
    $('#fancybox-left-ico, #fancybox-right-ico').css({
      opacity: 0
    });
    $('#fancybox-left, #fancybox-right').hover(function(e) {
      var enter = (e.type === "mouseenter"),
        dir = ($(this).is('#fancybox-left')) ?
          { left : (enter) ? '-30px' : 0 }:
          { right: (enter) ? '-30px' : 0 };
      dir.opacity = (enter) ? 1 : 0;
      $(this).find('span').stop().animate(dir, 400);
    });
  }
});
```

It doesn't slide out from under the image because the hoverable area needs to overlap it... if it was under, the hover wouldn't work.

Comment: Thanks for taking a lot at it fudgey. Unfortunately the code above is not working. Any other suggestions?

Comment: How is it not working? The demo works for you right? Is there something specific you expected to happen but isn't?

Comment: After inserting the code, nothing different happens. I've opened the demo in 4 different browsers and when I click on the image thumbnail, nothing happens. The image does not open in fancybox. Thanks for staying with this.

Comment: The site started blocking the css and image files, try the code. I'll update the demo.

Comment: So the demo is working now. After adding the code, still no change. Could the reason be since I'm using the normal fancybox and not the plugin?

Comment: You should also be using the plugin, so I'm not sure what you mean by "normal fancybox". Are you adding the `onComplete` callback in your original fancybox initialization code?

Comment: To clarify, I set up fancybox through the instructions on fancybox.net/howto and did not install a WordPress based plugin. How can I verify the onComplete callback has been added? Sorry but am new to jquery. Under the "$.fn.fancybox.defaults = {" section, "onComplete : function(){}," is what is coded. Also, the format I'm using for the fancybox layout is:                             $(".tip7").fancybox({
     'showCloseButton'   : false,
  'titlePosition'  : 'inside',
  'titleFormat'  : formatTitle
 });

Comment: Is your site live? Just from the last comment, it seems the modifications are being applied directly to the plugin? If so, the quotes are unnecessary. Try `$.fn.fancybox.defaults.onComplete = function(){ /* add the code above here */ };` Don't use `$.fn.fancybox.defaults = {}` because it will overwrite all of the other default values.

Comment: Ok great, making some progress. My site isn't live yet. But I added the code exactly how you said. The effect is working. There is one problem. I have specified the fancybox layout using $(".tip7").fancybox({ 'showCloseButton' : false, 'titlePosition' : 'inside', 'titleFormat' : formatTitle });. This styles fancybox in the same aesthetic as lightbox. See the first entry on http://fancybox.net/blog to see what I mean. When I insert the code at the location you described, fancybox is reverted back to its original styling and ignores the .tip7 modification. Thanks again.

Comment: Then actually, you should be adding the `onComplete` callback into that code: `$(".tip7").fancybox({ 'showCloseButton' : false, 'titlePosition' : 'inside', 'titleFormat' : formatTitle, onComplete = function(){ /* add the code above here */ } });`

Comment: THANK YOU! It works :). One last question, how can I define the distance the arrow slides? It's destination location is perfect. How can I now define the start location?

Comment: Also just noticed that after moving the mouse off #fancybox-right, the right arrow simply vanishes and does not slide left where it originated from. This is only for the right side as the left arrow does slide back right where it originated from. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: The `-30px` in the code above is the distance the arrow moves. The `0` is the starting position, so you can adjust that number and the `left` position of the arrow in the css to move initial position. I'm not sure about the right arrow not behaving for you, does it work in the demo as it should for you?

Comment: Thanks again. The demo behaves in a similar fashion where after hovering off #fancybox-right, the right arrow vanishes in place. After moving the mouse off #fancybox-left, the left arrow correctly slides back in the right direction to the point of its origin.

Comment: Look in the fancybox-1.3.4.css file and remove the `left: -9999px;` from the `#fancybox-left-ico, #fancybox-right-ico` definition. I've updated the demo link above.

Comment: Whew... I'm glad you got it :) So, if you are satisfied with this answer, please check it as accepted ( the check mark in the upper left corner )