# Fancybox next/previous not showing iframe

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, iframe

Hi guys is it possible to show next and previous button on fancy using iframe?
I tried using this code but its not showing.

```
     function open_photo(obj)
     {  
        $.fancybox({
         href : $(obj).attr("data-id"),
         width        : '75%',
         height       : '75%',
         autoScale      : true, 
         type         : 'iframe',
         overlayShow   : false,
         transitionIn  : 'elastic',
         transitionOut : 'elastic',
         centerOnScroll: true,
         showNavArrows : true
        });

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Its hard for me to answer without seeing all of your code but i found a few resources that might help

[Navigation arrows not working in fancybox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9827473/navigation-arrows-not-working-in-fancybox)

[fancybox navigation arrows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7536456/fancybox-navigation-arrows)

[Fancybox navigation arrows not showing up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8929879/fancybox-navigation-arrows-not-showing-up)